# Turning an indexed array into a dictionary in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, indexed

So I found on here this method to doing so but I don't understand exactly how to implement it.

```
extension Collection  {
    var indexedDictionary: [Int: Element] {
        return enumerated().reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.offset] = $1.element }
    }
}
```

so assuming I have an array of strings like

```
var someArray: [String] = ["String", "String", "String"...etc]
```

that I want to be indexed, making the end result being a dictionary like

`[1: "string", 2: "string":..etc]`

Using that method, how do I make that happen? Like where do I put the someArray into that code?

Comment: `let indexedDict = someArray.indexedDictionary`

Comment: `indexedDictionary` is a property not much different from `count` (in the way it's called, not its meaning). If you now how to access the array's `count`, then you know how to access the array's `indexedDictionary`.

Comment: Where do I or that vacawama?

Comment: Rmaddy so what you saying? I use count as in someArray.count

Comment: Beware, Maddy, I assume, Is very quick on the down vote button. That is not clear from the question title and the examples given that it has something to do with `indexedDictionary`. Had my answer down voted almost immediately, now deleted

Comment: Please fix the title so it talks about indexedDictionary.

Comment: @possen Don't make invalid assumptions about who may or may not have voted. And your (deleted) answer has no down votes.

Comment: @HarperCreek Please take this as the friendly advice it is intended to be. If you don't know how to access a property of a variable please pull up the Swift book and start reading from beginning. It's important to learn the basics of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extension:

```
extension Collection  {
    var indexedDictionary: [Int: Element] {
        return enumerated().reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.offset] = $1.element }
    }
}
```

adds the `indexedDictionary` property to all `Collection`s in Swift.  An array is a `Collection`, so arrays get this property added to them when you add this extension to a Swift source file at the top level (don't put it inside of another `class`, `struct`, or `enum`).  You only need to add this to one file in your project, and then the new property will be accessible in every file.

Then, you just call `indexedDictionary` on any array in your code and it returns a `Dictionary` of type `[Int : Element]` where `Element` represents the type in your original array.  So, if your array called `myArray` is of type `[String]`, then `myArray.indexedDictionary` will return a `Dictionary` of type `[Int : String]`.

---

**Examples:**

```
let arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
let dict1 = arr1.indexedDictionary
print(dict1)
```

Output:

> ```
> [2: "c", 0: "a", 1: "b"]
> ```

---

```
// It works with dictionary literals
let dict2 = [5, 10, 15].indexedDictionary
print(dict2)
```

Output:

> ```
> [2: 15, 0: 5, 1: 10]
> ```

---

```
  let arr3: [Any] = [true, 1.2, "hello", 7]
  print(arr3.indexedDictionary)
```

Output:

> ```
> [2: "hello", 0: true, 1: 1.2, 3: 7]
> ```

---

**Note:**  Dictionaries are unordered, so even though the order is unpredictable, the mapping of key to value is what you expect.

Comment: bless you and your heart.

Answer (score 1):

```
let result = someArray.reduce([:]) { (dic, val) -> [Int:String] in
    let index = someArray.index(of: val)
    var mutableDic = dic
    mutableDic[index!] = val
    return mutableDic
}
```